# AWS Lambda CloudTrail Events SAM Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-sam

Could you please provide information/link how can I create next via AWS SAM:

`1. Go to services → CloudWatch → Rules → click on Create rule .
 2. Event Source → choose Event Pattern → select CloudWatch Logs in Service Name , AWS API Call via CloudTrail in Event Type (If you don’t have Trail setup in CloudTrail, do first. To get help refer this document), CreateLogGroup in Specific operation(s)→ Targets → select Lambda function → select previously created lambda function → click on Configure details .
 3. Give Name, Description, State should be enabled → click on Create rule .`

(taken from https://medium.com/tensult/manage-aws-cloudwatch-log-group-retention-using-automation-26add478b0c5 article.)

I've not found any information how I can describe this Event Source / Event Type (AWS API Call via CloudTrail) for lambda function (step 2) in AWS SAM template.yaml file.

Sorry, if I provide not fully correct title to this question, I'm not sure how ask this properly - ping me, and I'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS SAM team answered that SAM didn't support CloudTrail+Lambda natively in SAM.
For more details check: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/550